# Setting up GitHub - resulted in massive files on local drive

Tags: xcode, git, github, ssh

I set up my first gitHub SSH key this morning and am having a few problems.

The first is that there is now a hidden .git file on my computer that is taking up 55.6GB of space.

I followed the instructions here to set up the SSH Key:
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/

When I tried to create a new repository I’m getting errors that  say “Xcode can’t verify the identity of a repository hosted on “github.com”

At this point I’m extremely confused where I went wrong.  Is it possible to delete all SSH Keys and anything local that is taking up space on my machine and start over?

File size screen: https://www.dropbox.com/s/chgyaxewl78zrik/git_file_Size.png?dl=0

Error on upload: https://www.dropbox.com/home/_IOS?preview=Screen+Shot+2016-10-03+at+6.17.29+PM.png

At this point, I would like to delete and SSH keys on my machine and basically start fresh.  If anyone has insight on how these massive files were formed please let me know, and if there are any tips on how to make sure this doesn’t happen are greatly appreciated.

Comment: `there is now a hidden .git file on my computer that is taking up 55.6GB` ... this file is the Git repo for what you clone from GitHub.

Comment: Thanks Tim. The file that I made a repository of is extremely small. Why would it take up so much room on my machine?

Comment: It could just have a ton of commits, or maybe some large binary files, or both.

Comment: Its a really really small file, and only has one comment. Can I trash those files with a program like omni disk sweeper? Will there be any repercussions?

Comment: No, this doesn't sound right.  Can you type `git log` and tell us what you see?

Comment: commit 235eb680994e2b8856434bca25eb986d0dc109e1
Author: John Doe <sheehan.megan@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Oct 3 17:33:10 2016 -0700

    first commit
Megan-Sheehan-Macbook-Pro:~ meganmitchell$

Comment: So you really just have one commit?  What is the size of the source code folder on your computer?

Comment: 55,389 bytes (238 KB on disk) for 12 items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git is a version control system. It allows you to control the changes on your files by making **snapshots** of how all your files (and then only changed files) look at the moment of the commit. You can read more how this awesome tool works [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics).

The problem is you have initialized or cloned a git repo on your home folder and git probably made a snapshot of all your files. You can safely `rm -rf ~/.git` to get rid of the repo.

Edit: Maybe you'll want to erase the code that was in the repo too. Next time you initiate a git repo, do it in a separate/isolated folder.

Comment: Thank you Jorgemdnt. I can enter that in terminal correct? Sorry.... extremely new to all of this.

Comment: I thought he cloned from GitHub but I read wrongly.  Yes, this sounds like a likely explanation.

Comment: @MLS1984 No problem at all being new, everyone starts somewhere. And you can enter that in the terminal.

Comment: I've entered rm -rf ~/.git in terminal. Should I delete the SSH key completely and set up again in a new isolated folder?

Comment: I am pretty sure your SSH keys and configs are not related with a single git repo. You can try making a new directory and cloning a repo in it from github  to see if it still works

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for all of your help. The terminal command deleted the large files and I'll restart with a new directory. Thank you!!